# How to add glympcon icons to the submit button in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, icons, submit

I want to add an `glympcon` `icon` to the `f.submit` or `f.button` . how can i do this in rails?

```
  <% if action?('new') %>
    <%= f.button "Save", :class=>"btn btn-primary  btn-sm" ,:id => "validation" do%>
      <i class='fa fa-plus'></i>Add Shift
    <%end%>
  <%else%>
  <%= f.button "Save", :class=>"btn btn-primary  btn-sm" ,:id => "validation"  do%>
    <i class='fa fa-save'></i>Edit Shift      
  <%end%>
  <%end%>
```

this is giving the `icons` what i want. but if there is any `model validation error` occurs in the `new` form i want to show the `text` of the `button` as `Add Shift` and similarly if any error occurs in `edit form` i want to show the `button` text as `Edit Shift`. How can i do this in rails?

Comment: Pls clarify how you want your desired result to look like. Do you want button text to save "Add Shift" instead of "Save" ? Where do you want the text to be placed? Is your question about adding icons (as subject says) or about adding (placing? showing?) custom text in event of errors?

Comment: for example i have a field "shift name" upon this field there is a presence validation. if validation fails in "new" action, then it renders the "new" page again. so here in this page, i want the button text to be "create shift" similarly when the validation fails in "edit" action it renders the same page again, in this i want the button text to be "edit shift" with the icons.

Comment: See if my answer helps. Also please update headline as it asks how to add icons to button, and it seems you want to alter button name based on presence of validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood what you want. If you use ActiveRecord presence validation, then target model object (the one you build form for) will have "errors" attribute present and available to you. The value of attribute is an array, so you can check any? on this.

You can either do checks directly in view, e.g.

```
 <%= f.button(@main_object.errors.any? "Add Shift" : "Save", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm", id: "validation") do %>
      <i class='fa fa-plus'></i><%= @main_object.errors.any? "empty??" : "Add Shift" %>
 <% end %>
```

Or you can define a helper method either for boolean value (hiding @main_object.errors.any? call), or returning string with proper label text based on this (or any other) check.

If you want to put either icon or label based on the same condition, simply do

```
 <%= f.button "Save", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm", id: "validation" do %>
      <%= "<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>" unless @main_object.errors.any? %>
      <% if !@main_object.errors.any? %> <i class='fa fa-plus'></i> <% end %>
      <%= "Add Shift" if @main_object.errors.any? %>
 <% end %>
```

Does it help?